# How to get the correct (Gaussian) units for electric and magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, units, dimensional-analysis

Friedman and Susskind in their *Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory* use the following Lagrangian for a charged particle in electromagnetic field characterized by the 4-vector potential $A_\mu$.
$$
L = -m\sqrt{1-{\dot{X}^i}^2} + e\dot{X}^\mu A_\mu
$$

From this, doesn't it follow that the dimensions of $A_\mu$ are that of $MQ^{-1}$? ($M$ and $Q$ are dimensions of mass and charge respectively.) Note that the distances are measured in units of time, so that when I mention a distance $x$, I actually mean $x/c$, hence $\dot{X}^\mu$'s are dimensionless.

Also, since $E_x =\partial_x A_0-\partial_t A_x$ and $B_x = \partial_y A_z-\partial_z A_y$, does't it follow that the electric and magnetic fields both have dimensions of $MQ^{-1}T^{-1}$? $T$ stands for dimensions of time.

Comment: i think susskind uses $\hbar = c = 1$ notation here.

Answer (score 0):

In the written Lagrangian is not in Gaussian units. Gaussian still keeps the c.
If it is in 'natural units', then e is dimensionless as are velocities.  Also, mass, energy, momentum, frequency, inverse time, inverse length all have the same units.  The units for each are chosen to be whatever is convenient, but should be the same for each object in a particular equation.  This means that  E and B have the same units as energy squared in natural units. What I mean by being the same for each object in an equation is that you wouldn't write an equation using centimeters on one side and feet on the other.

Comment: One other thing to note is that you put in the E and B.  They are not used in the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian.  They could be put in as shorthand, but they are not necessary.